# Unexpected run time error 1004. PDF not saving to folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code to pdf and save my file to a folder on my computer. I've tested in the past and had no problem. However, after making some minor changes i am getting run time error 1004. Any ideas on why this is? Very frustrating. Thank you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String

Set ws = Sheets("Multi")
Set wsJob = Sheets("Job")

FileName = ws.Range("B2")

    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To LastRow

        wsJob.Activate
        wsJob.Range("AZ1").Value = ws.Range("B" & i)
        wsJob.Range("AZ2").Value = ws.Range("C" & i)
        wsJob.Range("AZ3").Value = ws.Range("D" & i)
        wsJob.Range("AZ4").Value = ws.Range("E" & i)
        wsJob.Range("AZ5").Value = ws.Range("F" & i)
        wsJob.Range("AZ6").Value = ws.Range("G" & i)

        wsJob.ComboBox1.Visible = False
        wsJob.ComboBox2.Visible = False
        wsJob.ComboBox3.Visible = False
        wsJob.ComboBox4.Visible = False
        wsJob.ComboBox5.Visible = False
        wsJob.ComboBox6.Visible = False
        wsJob.CommandButton1.Visible = False

        wsJob.Rows("4:13").EntireRow.Hidden = True


        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=ws.Range("B2") & "TCC Analysis - " & ws.Range("B" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("C" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("D" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("E" & i) & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Next i

        wsJob.ComboBox1.Visible = True
        wsJob.ComboBox2.Visible = True
        wsJob.ComboBox3.Visible = True
        wsJob.ComboBox4.Visible = True
        wsJob.ComboBox5.Visible = True
        wsJob.ComboBox6.Visible = True
        wsJob.CommandButton1.Visible = True


        wsJob.Rows("4:13").EntireRow.Hidden = False


ws.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat...

Comment: it was working fine when I only used three values on the lines wsJob.Range("AZ6").Value =

Comment: if you do a `debug.print` on `ws.Range("B2") & "TCC Analysis - " & ws.Range("B" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("C" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("D" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("E" & i) & ".pdf", ` before the line that errors, do you get a valid path name?

Comment: yes, i have a similar loop that successfully pdfs and saves to that file path name

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line;

```
FileName:=ws.Range("B2") & "TCC Analysis - " & ws.Range("B" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("C" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("D" & i) & " - " & ws.Range("E" & i) & ".pdf"
```

with this;

```
FileName:=ws.Range("B2").value & "TCC Analysis - " & ws.Range("B" & i).value & " - " & ws.Range("C" & i).value & " - " & ws.Range("D" & i).value & " - " & ws.Range("E" & i).value & ".pdf"
```

Comment: That did not work. But, could it be that some of items in cells B&i are text values and not numerical?

Answer (score 0):

Replace;

```
    wsJob.Range("AZ1").Value = ws.Range("B" & i)
    wsJob.Range("AZ2").Value = ws.Range("C" & i)
    wsJob.Range("AZ3").Value = ws.Range("D" & i)
    wsJob.Range("AZ4").Value = ws.Range("E" & i)
    wsJob.Range("AZ5").Value = ws.Range("F" & i)
    wsJob.Range("AZ6").Value = ws.Range("G" & i)
```

with this;

```
    wsJob.Range("AZ1").Value = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
    wsJob.Range("AZ2").Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
    wsJob.Range("AZ3").Value = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
    wsJob.Range("AZ4").Value = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
    wsJob.Range("AZ5").Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
    wsJob.Range("AZ6").Value = ws.Range("G" & i).Value
```

Comment: That did not work. I think it does have to do with the values in B, C, and D. I tested with E, F, and G with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FileName = Sheets("Multi").Range("B2")
```

with this

```
FileName = Sheets("Multi").Range("B2").value
```

Change FileName decleration with different string because FileName is also using in the ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat line...